# Emacs narrow-by-regex

Tags: emacs, narrowing

There are functions like  `M-x narrow-to-line` and `M-x narrow-to-page`. Which routines can help me achieve functionality of non-existing  M-x narrow-by-regex?

Thanks.

Comment: What should `narrow-by-regex` do?

Comment: I had intention that It should only show me the lines matching by regex and I should be able to edit.    I found out that I can do M-x occur and do 'e' to edit the text.  This updates the remote buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work.  will prompt the user for the begin and end regex.  (not tested very thoroughly!):

```
(defun narrow-to-regex ()
  "narrow the buffer visibility to the section between two regexes the user provides"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((beginRegex (read-regexp "begin pattern"))
         (endRegex (read-regexp "end pattern"))
         (beg)
         (end))
    (goto-char (point-min)) ;; go to the start of the buffer
    (if (re-search-forward beginRegex nil t nil)
        (setq beg (- (point) (length beginRegex))))
    (if (re-search-forward endRegex nil t nil)
        (setq end (point)))
    (if (and beg end (> end beg))
        (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (message "did not find both instances of the regex, %s %s, no narrow" beg end))))
```

you will have too install it by putting it into a buffer (scratch etc) and going CTRL+X followed by CTRL+E